# SELENIUM: how to click on a blank section of webpage

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a search textbox, which has some default text "search your item" visible in it.
Once you click on the search box to enter any word, the default text disappears and the word is typed.

Now, if the word inside the search box is deleted and then you click on any place on the blank part of the page, then the default text appears.

I would like to simulate this using selenium. I am able to delete the word from the search box, but after deleting the word, how do i click on any blank part of the page so that the default text is visible again?

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you can use javascript into selenium to fire some event like focus or blur.

Comment: I am using python for selenium testing, so i am not sure if that would be possible. could you please give an example? tahnks

Comment: you can take a look here: http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/Selenium_JavaScript.htm ;)

Comment: can you just look for a div or something else and then click on it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the code:

> selenium.FireEvent("//id of the text box","blur");